# Adding multipart form-data to uploadTask(with:fromfile:) in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, file-upload, http-post, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a file (png, doc, jpg, etc...) to my server. However for me to save the file properly I'd like to add the file extension to my POST request. Apple.developer says *"The body stream and body data in this request object are ignored."* Is there a way to add body data to my request? Here's what I have so far:

```
func uploadFile(filePath: String, endpoint: String) -> Void {

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let url = URL(string: endpoint)!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

    let task = session.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: fileUrl)
    task.resume()

}
```

I tried to switch to using uploadTask(with:data:) but I am not sure how to add a file to data since most examples are using image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set boundary on URLSession.uploadTask :with :fromFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510888/set-boundary-on-urlsession-uploadtask-with-fromfile)